# Error when to resolve Double Hop issue with powershell

Tags: powershell

Today we need to resolve double hop issue with PowerShell.

But it is failed when we do following try:
Machines: client1, server1, networkpath

One client1 run following:

```
$session = New-PSSession -Computer server1 -Authentication Credssp  -Credential "username"
```

Following error thrown:

```
New-PSSession : [server1] Connecting to remote server server1 failed with the
following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. The
authentication mechanism requested by the client is not supported by the server
or unencrypted traffic is disabled in the service configuration. Verify the
unencrypted traffic setting in the service configuration or specify one of the
authentication mechanisms supported by the server.  To use Kerberos, specify the
computer name as the remote destination. Also verify that the client computer
and the destination computer are joined to a domain. To use Basic, specify
the computer name as the remote destination, specify Basic authentication and
provide user name and password. Possible authentication mechanisms reported by
server: Negotiate For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting
Help topic.
At line:1 char:12
+ $session = New-PSSession -Computer server1 -Authentication Credssp  -Creden ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotin    gTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

We have done following configuration:
Client1:

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer Server1
```

Server1:

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server
```

All servers are in workgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this solution in case someone is still having an issue with a simple resolution to DoubleHop without using CredSSP.

Try this out:
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Invoke-PSSession

It Invokes a PSSession, then Registers a PSSessionConfiguration with the Credentials that you provided. Basically providing the credentials for that DoubleHop

Answer (score 0):

Following suggestions from [Resolve Double-Hop Issue in PowerShell Remoting](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/847119/Resolve-Double-Hop-Issue-in-PowerShell-Remoting)

following steps can fix the err

1. Run gpedit.msc on **client**.
2. Expand to Local Computer Policy -> Computer
   Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Credentials
   Delegation.
3. Double click **Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication**.
4. Enable Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials.
5. Click Show... and add **wsman/Server1**.
6. Click several OK to close the popup dialogs.

Now we can run following script successful on client:

```
$session = New-PSSession -Computer server1 -Authentication Credssp  -Credential "username"
Enter-PSSession $session
Test-Path "NetWorkPath"
```